# python coding speed and cleanest

Tags: python

Python is pretty clean, and I can code neat apps quickly.
But I notice I have some minor error someplace and I dont find the error at compile but at run time. Then I need to change and run the script again. Is there a way to have it break and let me modify and run?

Also, I dislike how python has no enums. If I were to write code that needs a lot of enums and types, should I be doing it in C++? It feels like I can do it quicker in C++.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**"I don't find the error at compile but at run time"**

Correct.  True for all non-compiled interpreted languages.

**"I need to change and run the script again"**

Also correct.  True for all non-compiled interpreted languages.

**"Is there a way to have it break and let me modify and run?"**

What?

If it's a run-time error, the script breaks, you fix it and run again.

If it's not a proper error, but a logic problem of some kind, then the program finishes, but doesn't work correctly.  No language can anticipate what you hoped for and break for you.

Or perhaps you mean something else.

**"...code that needs a lot of enums"**

You'll need to provide examples of code that needs a lot of enums.  I've been writing Python for years, and have no use for enums.  Indeed, I've been writing C++ with no use for enums either.

You'll have to provide code that needs a lot of enums as a specific example.  Perhaps in another question along the lines of "What's a Pythonic replacement for all these enums."

It's usually polymorphic class definitions, but without an example, it's hard to be sure.

Comment: There *is* a way to break in case of exception, modify code, and run it. `pycopia` allows it (a script should be started from interactive prompt).

Comment: Your second 'true for all non-compiled interpreted languages' is not true for most versions of lisp or smalltalk. In lisp and error starts a debugger, you can modify the code then return to where you were in the program.

Comment: wow old question. This no enums interest me. I remember this specific project (my biggest python). I used enums for status such as server_unavailable, error, err404, busy, etc. I also stored it the database at certain times (like in a middle of a job if a user wants to stop/pause)

Comment: "I used enums for status such as server_unavailable, error, err404, busy, etc"?  Why?  Why not use words?

Answer (score 3):

With interpreted languages you have a lot of freedom.  Freedom isn't free here either.  While the interpreter won't torture you into dotting every i and crossing every T before it deems your code worthy of a run, it also won't try to statically analyze your code for all those problems.  So you have a few choices.

1) {Pyflakes, pychecker, pylint} will do static analysis on your code.  That settles the syntax issue mostly.

2) Test-driven development with nosetests or the like will help you.  If you make a code change that breaks your existing code, the tests will fail and you will know about it.  This is actually better than static analysis and can be as fast.  If you test-first, then you will have all your code checked at *test* runtime instead of program runtime.

Note that with 1 & 2 in place you are a bit better off than if you had just a static-typing compiler on your side. Even so, it will not create a proof of correctness.

It is possible that your tests may miss  some plumbing you need for the app to actually run. If that happens, you fix it by writing more tests usually.  But you still need to fire up the app and bang on it to see what tests you should have written and didn't.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into something like [nosey](http://jeffwinkler.net/2006/04/27/keeping-your-nose-green/), which runs your unit tests periodically when you've saved changes to a file. You could also set up a save-event trigger to run your unit tests in the background whenever you save a file (possible e.g. with Komodo Edit).

That said, what I do is bind the F7 key to run unit tests in the current directory and subdirectories, and the F6 key to run [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857) on the current file. Frequent use of these allows me to spot errors pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Python is an interpreted language, there *is* no compile stage, at least not that is visible to the user. If you get an error, go back, modify the script, and try again. If your script has long execution time, and you don't want to stop-restart, you can try a debugger like pdb, using which you can fix some of your errors during runtime.

There are a large number of ways in which you can implement enums, a quick google search for "python enums" gives everything you're likely to need. However, you should look into whether or not you really need them, and if there's a better, more 'pythonic' way of doing the same thing.